# Cookies or session variables that record user preferences for the whole site

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to setup cookies or session varibles to make the user preferences on a website remain on every page of the site, and I'm attempting to do it using Javascript, but I'm open to trying any code that works.

I want to make my onclick user options stay active for the user on every page of the website for their session. So if they navigate to page 2, their choice of layout from page 1 is remembered and remains active on page 2.

What I'm building is basically an ereader on a website, so I want the user to have the ability to change the font size, change the background color and change the text width to suit their preference. I've got all that working, but when they click to the next page, the settings clear, and they have to set them all again. I want the site to remember their choice for their whole session on the site or a length of time even if that's possible.

I'm very new to Javascript (it's my first day writing any), so the code below might be shockingly bad.

I don't know if I need to use a cookie or a session variable, but all the fixes I've found either don't work, or they aren't really meant for this purpose, so I can't use them.

In the code that I've created everything inside the 'story' div changes when the user clicks on an option above it, and the options are:

- Enlarge font
- Shrink Font
- Dark Theme
- Light Theme
- Sepia Theme
- Full Width
- 75% Width
- 50% Width

That all works so far, but I can't get it to stick with the user if they navigate to another page. The moment they click onto the next page, their preferences clear, and that is the problem.

Here is the code I have right now.

The HTML:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cookies.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="customize.js"></script>

 <style>
.text-tools{margin:auto; text-align:center;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="text-tools">
<img id="plustext" alt="Increase text size" src="images/A-plus.png" onclick="resizeText(1)" style="width:25px;" />
<img id="minustext" alt="Decrease text size" src="images/A-minus.png" onclick="resizeText(-1)" style="width:25px;" />
<a href="#" onclick="dark()"><img src="images/dark.png" style="width:25px;" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="light()"><img src="images/light.png" style="width:25px;" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="sepia()"><img src="images/sepia.png" style="width:25px;" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="full()"><img src="images/full.png" style="width:25px;" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="third()"><img src="images/third.png" style="width:25px;" /></a>
<a href="#" onclick="half()"><img src="images/half.png" style="width:25px;" /></a>
</div>
<div id="story">
<div id="sfont">
<div id="sbg">
<div id="stext">
<h1 id="chtitle">The Title</h1>
<p style="font-size:1em;font-color:#000;"><span id="cap1" style="font-size:2em;">S</span>ome text goes here...</p>
<a href="page2.html">Page Two</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p>Other stuff here</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

The Customize Javascript:

```
    // Change font size
function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize == "") {
    document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize = "1.0em";
  }
  document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}

//Change background color
<!--//

function dark()

{
document.getElementById("sbg").style.backgroundColor="#474747"
document.getElementById("stext").style.color="#cdcdcd"
document.getElementById("chtitle").style.color="#e5e5e5"
document.getElementById("cap1").style.color="#e5e5e5"
}

function light()

{
document.getElementById("sbg").style.backgroundColor="#ffffff"
document.getElementById("stext").style.color="#8C9398"
document.getElementById("chtitle").style.color="#686868"
document.getElementById("cap1").style.color="#686868"
}

function sepia()

{
document.getElementById("sbg").style.backgroundColor="#c1b29b"
document.getElementById("stext").style.color="#77674f"
document.getElementById("chtitle").style.color="#564a36"
document.getElementById("cap1").style.color="#564a36"

}

//Change div width
function full()

{
document.getElementById('story').setAttribute("style","width:100%;margin:auto");
}

function third()

{
document.getElementById('story').setAttribute("style","width:75%;margin:auto");
}

function half()

{
document.getElementById('story').setAttribute("style","width:50%;margin:auto");
}

//-->
```

This is the Cookies Javascript that doesn't work:

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

I'm pretty certain that I'm not using the cookies.js correctly, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any help with fixing the cookies.js, so that it works or an alternative method would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance to anyone who fancies tackling this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your Cookies Javascript and it is working fine.
If you want your user options to stay active on every page of the website for their session, you might want to consider using `sessionStorage`.

Your Customize Javascript is working, despite the syntax errors.

My advice is to save the user options as they are setting them, and reading them in every page that is loaded after that.

Here is the Customize Javascript you need. I also corrected the syntax. I would use sessionStorage for this case because this way you don't need cookies.

```
window.onload = loadSettings;
// Change font size
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("fontSize", multiplier);
    if (document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize == "") {
        document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize = "1.0em";
    }
    document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sfont").style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}

function dark() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("background", "dark");
    document.getElementById("sbg").style.backgroundColor = "#474747";
    document.getElementById("stext").style.color = "#cdcdcd";
    document.getElementById("chtitle").style.color = "#e5e5e5";
    document.getElementById("cap1").style.color = "#e5e5e5";
}

function light() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("background", "light");
    document.getElementById("sbg").style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    document.getElementById("stext").style.color = "#8C9398";
    document.getElementById("chtitle").style.color = "#686868";
    document.getElementById("cap1").style.color = "#686868";
}

function sepia() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("background", "sepia");
    document.getElementById("sbg").style.backgroundColor = "#c1b29b";
    document.getElementById("stext").style.color = "#77674f";
    document.getElementById("chtitle").style.color = "#564a36";
    document.getElementById("cap1").style.color = "#564a36";
}

//Change div width
function full() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("divWidth", "full");
    document.getElementById('story').setAttribute("style", "width:100%;margin:auto");
}

function third() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("divWidth", "third");
    document.getElementById('story').setAttribute("style", "width:75%;margin:auto");
}

function half() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("divWidth", "half");
    document.getElementById('story').setAttribute("style", "width:50%;margin:auto");
}

function loadSettings() {
    var fontSize = sessionStorage.getItem("fontSize") && parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem("fontSize"));
    var background = sessionStorage.getItem("background") && sessionStorage.getItem("background");
    var divWidth = sessionStorage.getItem("divWidth") && sessionStorage.getItem("divWidth");
    resizeText(fontSize);
    if (background == "dark") dark();
    else if (background == "light") light();
    else if (background == "sepia") sepia();
    if (divWidth == "full") full();
    else if (divWidth == "third") third();
    else if (divWidth == "half") half();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use localStorage to save the information. Cookies will send the information to the server every time that you make an HTTP request, such as getting a new page. Also, they don't save as much information. [w3schools has a page on localStorage and sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp) that might be worth looking at.

In an attempt to modify your code as little as possible, what I would suggest is that you define a new function that stores what functions it is to call and then calls them.

```
function update(key, funct) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, funct);
    window[funct].call();
}
```

You will need to change your links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="update('color','dark')">...
<a href="#" onclick="update('color','light')">...
<a href="#" onclick="update('color','sepia')">...
<a href="#" onclick="update('size','full')">...
<a href="#" onclick="update('size','third')">...
<a href="#" onclick="update('size','half')">...
```

When you load a new page you can check if the given setting has been changed and call the function to perform the given changes.

```
if (funct = localStorage.getItem('color')) {
    window[funct].call();
}
if (funct = localStorage.getItem('size')) {
    window[funct].call();
}
```

What is preferable though is to do this in a loop:

```
var functs = ['color', 'size'];
for (var i=0; i < functs.length; i++) {
    if (funct = localStorage.getItem(functs[i])) {
        window[funct].call();
    }
}
```

To see a working example save the following code to an html file within your webserver and load it within your web browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>

    // Define fuctions: dark, light, etc. so that they just print their names
    var fs = ['dark', 'light', 'sepia', 'full', 'third', 'half']
    for (var i=0; i < fs.length; i++) {
        var f = fs[i];
        window[f] = (function(funct) {
            return function() {
                alert(funct);
            }
        })(f)
    }

    // Update localStorage and call function
    function update(key, funct) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, funct);
        window[funct].call();
    }

    // Page has loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        // Call functions when page is loaded
        var functs = ['color', 'size'];
        for (var i=0; i < functs.length; i++) {
            if (funct = localStorage.getItem(functs[i])) {
                window[funct].call();
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="update('color','dark')">dark</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="update('color','light')">light</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="update('color','sepia')">sepia</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="update('size','full')">full</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="update('size','third')">third</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="update('size','half')">half</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use the console for debugging, I would recommend changing `alert` in the code to `console.log`. It's less intrusive.

Comment: Thank you for working on this. I went with the first answer, but I'm still learning, so this answer might help me learn a bit more.